# IBM Cloud Private 3.1.1 EE Installation Error

Tags: installation, ibm-cloud-private

I'm doing a fresh installation of IBM Cloud Private 3.1.1 in a lab environment with the following components :

- 1 x boot node
- 1 x master node
- 1 x proxy node
- 1 x worker
- 1 x management node
- 1 x VA node
- 1 x etcd node

The installation failed at the task : "addon : Installing logging chart".

All nodes are using Ubuntu 16, and the installation was initiated from the boot node with root user credentials

Looked into the tiller log, I found :

```
[tiller] 2018/11/30 12:30:44 executing 7 post-install hooks for logging
[tiller] 2018/11/30 12:30:44 deleting post-install hook logging-elk-elasticsearch-tls-init for release logging due to "before-hook-creation" policy
[kube] 2018/11/30 12:30:44 Starting delete for "logging-elk-elasticsearch-tls-init" Job
[kube] 2018/11/30 12:30:44 Using reaper for deleting "logging-elk-elasticsearch-tls-init"
[kube] 2018/11/30 12:30:44 building resources from manifest
[kube] 2018/11/30 12:30:44 creating 1 resource(s)
[kube] 2018/11/30 12:30:44 Watching for changes to Job logging-elk-elasticsearch-tls-init with timeout of 10m0s
[kube] 2018/11/30 12:30:44 Add/Modify event for logging-elk-elasticsearch-tls-init: ADDED
[kube] 2018/11/30 12:30:44 logging-elk-elasticsearch-tls-init: Jobs active: 0, jobs failed: 0, jobs succeeded: 0
[kube] 2018/11/30 12:30:44 Add/Modify event for logging-elk-elasticsearch-tls-init: MODIFIED
[kube] 2018/11/30 12:30:44 logging-elk-elasticsearch-tls-init: Jobs active: 1, jobs failed: 0, jobs succeeded: 0
[tiller] 2018/11/30 12:38:53 warning: Release logging post-install ibm-icplogging/templates/es-searchguard-init-job.yaml could not complete: watch closed before Until timeout
[tiller] 2018/11/30 12:38:53 warning: Release "logging" failed post-install: watch closed before Until timeout
[storage] 2018/11/30 12:38:53 updating release "logging.v1"
[tiller] 2018/11/30 12:38:53 failed install perform step: watch closed before Until timeout
```

Any suggestion would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Are You Have Been Followed System Requirement ?
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSBS6K_3.1.1/supported_system_config/hardware_reqs.html

*Other Problem :
To resolve the OOM (OutOfMemory) issue we could try to double both the limit and the java opts (ES_JAVA_OPTS) for ***elasticsearch***, You can run the following command:

**kubectl edit -n kube-system statefulset logging-elk-data**

and double the parameters.